# Testing SC (supplementary characters) support in SQL Server on a non SC database still shows SC characters are working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was reading up about about SC (supplementary characters) support in SQL Server and particularly found this article interesting:

https://devio.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/supplementary-characters-in-sql-server/

A short sample code to test SC was provided and I have modified it a bit to try on a non-SC database as below.

```
DROP TABLE test_sc 
GO 

DECLARE @d nvarchar(10) =  N'';

SELECT 
    @d [character], 
    UNICODE(@d) [point_code],  
    NCHAR(UNICODE(@d)) [character_unicode], 
    LEN(@d) [len], DATALENGTH(@d) [datalength]
INTO test_sc
GO 

DECLARE @d nvarchar(10)  =  N''

INSERT INTO test_sc 
    SELECT 
        NCHAR(143743), 
        UNICODE(@d), NCHAR(UNICODE(@d)), LEN(@d), DATALENGTH(@d) 
GO 

SELECT * FROM test_sc
```

The results that I get are as below:

[image]

I am just wondering as to why the first row first column still shows the correct character despite lack of collation support. Does this indicate that a non-SC database actually supports some SC characters correctly.

Comment: Applications, including SSMS, can still store and retrieve supplementary characters because they're writing UTF-16 data directly into the nvarchar columns. The SQL Server string handling functions won't recognize any supplementary characters, though, unless the database itself is using an _SC supplementary collation. Microsoft outlines the behavior differences of the various string handling functions at [Supplementary characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support#Supplementary_Characters).

Comment: ok, and yet some characters also do not work, like the second row example. How come some work and some do not?

Comment: Because `NCHAR(143743)` returns `null` on a database that's not using an _SC supplementary characters collation. As per the link in my first comment, _A value higher than 0xFFFF returns NULL instead of the corresponding surrogate._

Comment: But both of those examples have a point code > 0xFFFF

Comment: If you do `DECLARE @d nvarchar(10)  =  N''` in your second block, you'll see this also doesn't work. It's not the character itself that's problematic but the way it's inserted. A raw string as supplied by SSMS will not have to be further interpreted by the engine, so it doesn't matter that its functions do not support the characters.

Comment: No. I tried that. And it still works--the character displays. The second row still consistently does not display

Comment: Let's try this again, then. The Unicode types in SQL Server allow *any* byte sequence to be stored and retrieved as-is (including invalid ones, even). In that sense the collation does *not* determine what characters can be stored and retrieved, unlike for non-Unicode types. So if you write `N'...'` and insert that literal into a column, you can always retrieve it, and SSMS will display it correctly. But what will *not* work correctly is calling `UNICODE`, `NCHAR`, `LEN` or any other function on supplementary characters, these give incorrect results. That's what the query illustrates.

Comment: _But both of those examples have a point code > 0xFFFF_ Do they? The Unicode function says they are 55360 (0xD840) and 55372 and (0xD84C) because it's only looking at the first two bytes of the string.

Comment: The point code result is clearly wrong in a non-SC database -- this is explained in the link that was in my original post. In an SC database, the point code will give the correct values which is > 0xFFFF